# How to remove shadow of a card view if I make it clickable

Tags: java, kotlin, mvvm

I am using Card View , and a library to make blur around cardview. I made card view clickable but when I click it it appears a shadow. I am not talking about corners and about cardElevation="0dp" but clicking a card view

I tried using focusable="false" and cardElevation="0dp" but it didn't work

Comment: Make sure you are using app level and not and android level cardElevation
`app:cardElevation="0dp"`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just have put the onClick event in Layout not in Card View and solved my problem